# "mysqli_connect" não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Não estou conseguindo usar a função "mysqli_connect". Alguém pode me ajudar? Está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   /home/vagrant/Projetos/products/app/Database/Connection.php on line 11

O meu código é esse:

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\Connection;

class Connection
{
   protected $host = '127.0.0.1';
   protected $user = 'homestead';
   protected $password = 'secret';
   protected $database = 'products_crud';
   protected $connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);  
}
```

O erro acontece nessa linha de código:

```
protected $connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que para fazer o que deseja você deva utilizar o [`__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php), dessa forma quando fizer o `new Connection()`, por exemplo, você irá automaticamente acionar o `construct()`, ele é capaz de definir a variável como deseja.

Por exemplo:

```
namespace App\Database\Connection;

class Connection
{
    protected $host = '127.0.0.1';
    protected $user = 'homestead';
    protected $password = 'secret';
    protected $database = 'products_crud';
    protected $connection;

    function __construct(){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
    }
}
```

Você pode ver o que é suportado [aqui](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs), apenas **alguns** exemplos do que você **não pode fazer**, **resumidamente**, (*ao menos não na versão 7.1*):

```
protected $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Definir o $ip com base em uma variável "run-time".
```

```
protected $enviar = function($email){
 //...
}
// Utilizar o $enviar como uma função.
```

```
protected $calculo = bcadd('10', '20');
// Definir o $calculo com base na execução de uma função (isto foi o que você fez).
```

---

Bem, existe muito mais coisa que não pode fazer, mas é mais fácil [ver aqui o que é permitido fazer](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs). ;)